# Changing text with javascript

Tags: javascript, dom

I am trying to write a simple script.

Here is the idea:

I have a div element and dynamically created paragraph element inside div. Paragraph element contains some text. I also have a link on the page. I want the text changed to other text (predefined) when clicking the link. I have 2 functions: one function for creating paragraph element and appending it to div. Second function is for changing the text. I believe the issue has something to do with passing the variables from one function to another

Here is HTML:

```
<a href='' onclick='changeText();return false;'>Change Text</a>

    <div id='box'></div>
```

And here is JS code:

```
var x = document.getElementById('box');

        window.onload = function createEl(){

            var p = document.getElementsByTagName('div')[0];
            var el = document.createElement('p');

                var text = "Hello";
                p.appendChild(el);
                var res = document.createTextNode(text);
                el.appendChild(res);
}


function changeText(){

    text.innerHTML = 'other text';


}
```

Answer (score 0):

You suspected correctly. However, rather than fix what were doing wrong in your script (as you made several beginner mistakes), I slightly rewrote it and explained what each thing does as I do it. Here's a version of your script that should work:

```
// we define these variables outside of any functions
// this means they're global and any function can get
// access to them.
var box_div, el;

window.onload = function createEl() {
    // get references to div element
    box_div = document.getElementById('box');

    // create a new <p> element and store it in 'el'
    el = document.createElement('p');

    // add text to the new <p> element
    el.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Hello"));

    // append the new <p> element to the div
    box_div.appendChild(el);
}

function changeText() {
    // since we have a reference to the <p> element
    // already, we can just do this:
    el.innerHTML = 'other text';
}​
```